# Github actions dynamic workflow name

Tags: github-actions

I have a manually triggered job that builds and deploys an image based on the tag I specify. Is there a way to make the workflow name dynamic?

```yaml
name: Build and push

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      tag:
        description: 'Image Tag'
        required: true

jobs:
...
```

I would like to do something like

```yaml
name: "Build and push ${{ github.event.inputs.tag }}"
```

Comment: What is the purpose?

Comment: we have a team of ~4 that uses actions on this repo, it would be great to have a glance of who built which image when on the `/actions` page.
For example if someone on my team built 0.1.1, I would have to either ping a group chat or click on the latest workflow to find out the latest image tag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of Sep 26th 2022, this is now supported. Here's the announcement (which contains a link to the documentataion): https://github.blog/changelog/2022-09-26-github-actions-dynamic-names-for-workflow-runs/

Comment: This is only for public Github. How about Enterprise?

Comment: Enterprise works too

Answer (score 3):

Workflow names are not dynamic, but fixed.

To get at the actual data of a workflow run, you'll have to chose the specific run from the *Actions > All Workflows > [name-of-your-workflow]* list.

Alternatively, you can think about other ways to propagate the outcomes of your builds.

- Our team, for example, propagates build outcomes to teams **chat channel** (in our case Microsoft Teams using the action [notify-microsoft-teams](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/notify-microsoft-teams)). If you search the market place you'll find plenty of actions for this.
- Another alternative could be to generated **custom badges**, which you could then make visible to your team. A nice action for this is [bring-your-own-badge](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/bring-your-own-badge).
- Last but not least you can propagate your workflow run data using **emails** (again, there are actions which do this for you).

Comment: Thanks, I found a (in my case) Slack hook to be the best workaround. Creating releases/tags from each build was also a decent but noisy approach.

Comment: We also hook into slack and show who caused the action to fire and what server and other tags. It is helpful, but I would like to see this info on the "All Workflows" screen in github.  That would be more useful than the same name for every run.  Our build can build a number of different systems, all handled by the same action.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using `run-name` instead of `name` for naming your action.

```yaml
run-name: "Build and push ${{ github.event.inputs.tag }}"
```